# Content controls have to be top-level controls

Tags: asp.net

I have a website that can be accessed from www.blahblah.com and special.blahblah.com.  The www site always works but occasionly I get a 'Content controls have to be top-level controls in a content page or a nested master page that references a master page' error on the special site.

It's exactly the same code running in both situations and the offending page doesn't even have a master page.  Why would it work all the time on one and fail sometimes on the other?

Answer (score 5):

If anyone gets this error message when dynamically switching master pages, make sure your code is

```
MasterPageFile = "TheMasterPage.master"
```

Not

```
this.master.MasterPageFile = "TheMasterPage.master"
```

Answer (score 4):

Just got this problem.
It was because we had a tag ending with double slashes:

```
<//asp:HyperLink>
```

Answer (score 3):

Look for an unclosed tag in one of your server controls, im running VS2010 and the IDE aspx validator didnt pick up on the unclosed tag

Answer (score 2):

It can also happen if you put a tag on a website, then another one in the middle of that one and you close the second outside the first so they kinda cut themselves if you know what I mean

Answer (score 1):

My issue was that i mixed up `<ASP:CONTENT` with `<ASP:ContentPlaceholder`

`<ASP:CONTENT` goes on the content file...not the Master pages!  Ensure you're using the correct control.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I was trying to make a RequiredFieldValidator self-closing.  The control must have separate ending tag: `</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>.`

THIS WILL CAUSE THE ERROR:
`<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvx"` `runat="server"ErrorMessage="`*`</b>"ControlToValidate="xxx" />`

GOOD SYNTAX:
`<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvx" runat="server" ErrorMessage="`*`</b>"ControlToValidate="xxx" ></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>`