# I have a website that whenever I debug it the browser gives me and error.

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have no idea what is causing this error, if you need to see my code just let me know, its a MasterPage.master that is attached to my default.aspx.

This is the error I get in the browser:

```
Server Error in '/WebSite1' Application.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Content controls have to be top-level controls in a content page or a nested master page that references a master page. 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.Web.HttpException: Content controls have to be top-level controls in a content page or a nested master page that references a master page.

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.  

Stack Trace: 


[HttpException (0x80004005): Content controls have to be top-level controls in a content page or a nested master page that references a master page.]
   System.Web.UI.MasterPage.CreateMaster(TemplateControl owner, HttpContext context, VirtualPath masterPageFile, IDictionary contentTemplateCollection) +8690104
   System.Web.UI.Page.get_Master() +51
   System.Web.UI.Page.ApplyMasterPage() +15
   System.Web.UI.Page.PerformPreInit() +45
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +282




--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.5466; ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.5456
```

Comment: `Content controls have to be top-level controls in a content page or a nested master page that references a master page.`  You're misusing `<asp:ContentControl>`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/835877/master-page-weirdness-content-controls-have-to-be-top-level-controls-in-a-con

Answer (score 0):

Look for an unclosed tag, or an invalid closing of a tag in one of your server controls.

[Content controls have to be top-level controls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/313442/content-controls-have-to-be-top-level-controls)